# Aumentar un array en Java

Tags: java, array

Buen dia a todos, el ejercicio que necesito hacer es el siguiente:
Tengo un **Array1 = {1,2,3,4,5}**, pero necesito copiar ese array cuantas veces necesite dentro de otro array, por ejemplo multiplico ese array 3 veces Array2 = {1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5} he intenado con este codigo dentro de una clase especial para este ejercicio pero no me funciona ni con el while ni con el for:

```
public void completarCantidades(){
    this.cantidadElementosAmpliado = this.cortes.length * cantidadObjetos ;
    this.cortesAmpliado = new float[cantidadElementosAmpliado];
    setJ(0);
    setK(0);
    setN(0);
    while (this.j < this.cantidadObjetos) {            
        
        while (this.k < this.cortes.length) {                
          this.cortesAmpliado[this.n] = this.cortes[this.k];
          this.n ++;
          this.k ++;

        }
        this.k = 0;
        this.j ++;
    }
```

Comment: ya intentaste con `java.lang.System.arraycopy()`???

Answer (score 1):

prueba esto.

```
public void extendArray(int[] arr, int n){ //arr seria tu array original, n la cant de veces a multiplicar
int[] arr_new = int[arr.length() * n];
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
while(i < n){ 
   for(int k = 0; k < arr.length(); k++){
       arr_new[j] = arr[k];
       j++;
   }
i++;
}
```